# ES6 function. What is the difference?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What is the difference between

```
displayFunction() {
  console.log('test')
}
```

and

```
const displayFunction = () => {
  console.log('test')
}
```

I code in Angular a bit and saw the first  way of defining methods all the time. However, React seems to prefer the second way.

Comment: check this out: https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/

Comment: the es6 function will be transpiled to this: var displayFunction = function displayFunction(){ console.log('test')}

Comment: see this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)